# USD Currency Formatting in Java

Tags: java, string, currency

In Java, how can I efficiently convert floats like `1234.56` and similar BigDecimals into Strings like `$1,234.56`

I'm looking for the following:

String `12345.67` becomes String `$12,345.67`

I'm also looking to do this with `Float` and `BigDecimal` as well.

Answer (score 39):

There's a locale-sensitive idiom that works well:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

// Get a currency formatter for the current locale.
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println(fmt.format(120.00));
```

If your current locale is in the US, the `println` will print $120.00

Another example:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

Locale locale = new Locale("en", "GB"); // United Kingdom
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
System.out.println(fmt.format(120.00));
```

This will print: £120.00

Answer (score 9):

```
DecimalFormat moneyFormat = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
System.out.println(moneyFormat.format(1234.56));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code according to your input and output::

The output of the program is $12,345.67 for both BigDecimal and number and it works for float also.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
        String pattern = "$#,##0.###";
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("12345.67");

        String bigDecimalConvertedValue = decimalFormat.format(bigDecimal);
        String convertedValue = decimalFormat.format(12345.67);

        System.out.println(bigDecimalConvertedValue);
        System.out.println(convertedValue);
    }
}
```