# Converting from formatted string to double and vice versa

Tags: java, string, double, currency

I need to convert formatted strings to double and vice versa.

$40.00 will be 40.00 ( and vice versa )

$80,000.00 will be 80000.00 ( and vice versa )

So far I can format the string, by taking out the dollar symbol and commas, but I can't convert double back to the formatted string with the dollar symbol and commas in the right place.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance-java.util.Locale-

Comment: I would recommend you search for [formatting currency](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+formatting+currency) and read a little.

Comment: possible duplicate of [USD Currency Formatting in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075743/usd-currency-formatting-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, you could do it with a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");
    String[] arr = { "$40.00", "$80,000.00" };
    for (String str : arr) {
        try {
            double dbl = nf.parse(str).doubleValue();
            System.out.printf("%s = %.2f and %s%n", str, dbl,
                    nf.format(dbl));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
$40.00 = 40.00 and $40.00
$80,000.00 = 80000.00 and $80,000.00
```

Comment: You can add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` before output to get rid of numbers formatting.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it needs to be placed in separate line. My bad.

Comment: @Pshemo Awesome! Thanks for the demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the dollars and the comas with nothing using Regualar Expression . Regular expression is a very useful skill to have and extremely easy to learn.

Here is a [cheat sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) for it. Its fairly easy to learn. Try to come up with something and if you get stuck somewhere reach out

Then use Double.parseDouble wrapper class method to convert a string to a double.

Comment: There's no need to go that technical and use regular expressions when Java already provides you `NumberFormat`.

Comment: It just another way to accomplishing this. I often use it for string manipulation